# Problems loading configuration with Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am trying to mapping a Mysql table with Hibernate, but I get the next error when I execute the application:

```
Error creando una factoria de session.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid   configuration
oct 04, 2014 10:23:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [com.Utiles.Controlador.ControladorInsertar]        en el contexto con ruta [/Libreria] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una      excepción] con causa raíz
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 25; El documento no es válido:    no se ha encontrado la gramática.
```

I have this Eclipse files configuration:[image]

This is my Hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

 <hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-  configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/proyecto</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<mapping resource="com.Utiles.Libro.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this my Libro.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping package="com.Utiles">
<class name="Libro" table="libros">
    <id name="isbn" type="String" />
    <property name="titulo" type="String" column="titulo" />
    <property name="categoria" type="String" column="categoria" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Coud you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you need to assign type of property either with full class name `java.lang.String` or with predefined type `string`. So update your Libro.xml to;

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
             "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping package="com.Utiles">
    <class name="Libro" table="libros">
        <id name="isbn" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="titulo" type="java.lang.String" column="titulo" />
        <property name="categoria" type="java.lang.String" column="categoria" />
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Also try to add `DOCTYPE` in your Libro.xml

Hope it helps.

Comment: Try again, I updated my answer. But also, you should provide more information? Libro source, ControladorInsertar source...

Comment: It works!!!Adding DOCTYPE header, the configuration could be loaded and the database was modified correctly. Thanks a lot

Comment: Another question...what must I do if I want to replace this xml for Hibernate annotations? In Hibernate 3 it was with @Entity and @@Table(name="Libros") annotations in Libro class, but I think that they are deprecated.

Comment: They aren't deprecated, you can use it. Also, how to setup project to use annotation is one of FAQ questions, so google it. Here is official hibernate tutorial http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html